# regular expression that matches anything

Tags: regex

What will be regular expression that accept every thing?
For example 
I have a url string /vpv/?pid=FLR1&deviceType=flash#exterior/backplate . Now I want to write regex like

```
 /vpv/?(any thing : alphabet,number,special chars, )#[exterior/](anything here)
```

value within() can be anything.

Comment: Try this /vpv/?[^\s]*\b

Comment: Have you actually read anything about regular expressions? That's about the most basic thing at all...

Comment: I should better read that .. thanks for sugessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .* in the brackets to accomplish this ...

Answer (score 1):

What about the `dot` character?

[image: Dot]

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can play with regular expressions using this http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ write your examples and it will highlight in realtime what is found. so you can play around :D